# How to capture chown output in a ksh script

Tags: ksh, chown

I have written a script to change file ownerships based on an input list read in. My script works fine on directories without space in their name. However it fails to change files on directories with space in their name. I also would like to capture the output from the chown command to a file. Could anyone help ?

here is my script in ksh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

newowner=eg27395

dirname=/home/sas/sastest/
logfile=chowner.log
date > $dir$logfile
command="chown $newowner:$newowner"    
for fname in list
do
in="$dirname/$fname"                    
if [[ -e $in  ]]                        
then
     while  read  line
    do
            tmp=$(print "$line"|awk '{if (substr($2,1,1) == "/" )  print $2; if (substr($0,1,1) == "/" )  print '})         
            if [[  -e $tmp  ]]                                                                                     
           then
                    eval  $command \"$tmp\"                                        
             fi
    done < $in
else
        echo "input file $fname is not present. Check file location in the script."
fi
done
```

Comment: I bet you don't need awk at all: what's in the "list" file?

Comment: List file and several other input files that could be added to the for loop contains report of files users have left behind. I strip the file names from these files and then try to change ownership on them with the current user so that disk could be managed.

Comment: But your awk command indicates there are 2 fields per line. What is in that file? This may be the source of your problems

Comment: I have no problem stripping the files. Here is the example of input file:      1)   File Name: driver2.ZIP
          Size in Megabyte: 254   
            Location: /sasdev/dropzone/dm_etl/HB/IRS/2014/AugME/driver2.ZIP   
/sasdev/dropzone/dm_etl/HB/IRS/2014/DecME/driver2.ZIP
/sasdev/dropzone/dm_etl/HB/IRS/2014/NovME/driver2.ZIP
         Created on: 03 Sep 2014

Comment: Please update your question. You can't format a comment with multiple lines

Comment: This editor isn't easy to work with. Sorry I couldn't get it to display it right. any way I was able to solve the output problem using done < $in >> $logfile 2>&1 . Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The eval is stripping the quotes on this line

```
command="chown $newowner:$newowner"
```

In order to get the line to work with spaces you will need to provide backslashed quotes

```
command="chown \"$newowner:$newowner\""
```

This way the command that eval actually runs is

```
chown "$newowner:$newowner"
```

Also, you probably need quotes around this variable setting, although you'll need to tweak the syntax

```
tmp="$(print "$line"|awk '{if (substr($2,1,1) == "/" )  print $2; if (substr($0,1,1) == "/" )  print '})"
```

To capture the output you can add 2>&1 > file.out where file.out is the name of the file ... in order to get it working with eval as you are using it you will need to backslash any special characters much in the same way you need to backslash the double quotes

Comment: Thanks James for your useful comments. I still can't send the output to the output file. seems chown doesn't like output file and sends everything to the screen. ls -l though works       #chown  "$newowner:$newowner" "$tmp"
                        ls -l $logfilepath
                fi
        done <  $in >> $logfilepath

Answer (score 1):

a couple of other errors:

- `date > $dir$logfile` -- no `$dir` variable defined
- to safely read from a file: `while IFS= read -r line`

But to answer your main concern, don't try to build up the command so dynamically: don't bother with the `$command` variable, don't use `eval`, and quote the variable.

```
chmod "$newowner:$newowner" "$tmp"
```

Comment: Thanks Glen. I simplified the chown line as you indicated: chown  "$newowner:$newowner" "$tmp" but I can't create the output file as chown seems don't like the output file and sends everything to screen. ls -l $logfile >> $output however works.

Comment: No syntax error, but permission error. Since I don't have the root previlage. Once the script is complete I pass it to the root admin to run

Comment: chown: /home/sas/sastest/testdir/mars_auto_score_2010.sas7bdat: Operation not permitted.
chown: /home/sas/sastest/testdir/Inforce Mart/test_in: Operation not permitted.

Comment: This shows up in the screen and I can't capture it to the file. with ls it goes to the ouput file.

Comment: Then you want `chmod "$newowner:$newowner" "$tmp" 2>"$logfile"` to capture the error

Answer (score 1):

Your example code suggests that list is a "meta" file: A list of files that each has a list of files to be changed. When you only have one file you can remove the while loop.
When list is a variable with filenames you need `echo "${list}"| while ...`.
It is not completely clear why you sometimes want to start with the third field. It seems that sometimes you have 2 words before the filename and want them to be ignored. Cutting the string on spaces becomes a problem when your filenames have spaces as well. The solution is look for a space followed by a slash: that space is not part of a filename and everything up to that space can be deleted.

```
newowner=eg27395

# The slash on the end is not really part of the dir name, doesn't matter for most commands
dirname=/home/sas/sastest
logfile=chowner.log
# Add braces, quotes and change dir into dirname
date > "${dirname}/${logfile}"

# Line with command not needed

# Is list an inputfile? It is streamed using "< list" at the end of while []; do .. done
while IFS= read -r fname; do
   in="${dirname}/${fname}"
   # Quotes are important
   if [[ -e "$in"   ]]; then
      # get the filenames with a sed construction, and give it to chmod with xargs
      # The sed construction is made for the situation that in a line with a space followed by a slash
      # the filename starts with the slash
      # sed is with # to avoid escaping the slashes
      # Do not redirect the output here but after the loop.
      sed 's#.* /#/#' "${in}" | xargs chmod ${newowner}:${newowner}
   else
       echo "input file ${fname} is not present. Check file location in the script."
   fi
done < list >> "${dirname}/${logfile}"
```

Comment: Thanks Walter, very useful comments. I can't create the output file as chown seems don't like the output file and sends everything to screen. ls -l $logfile >> $output however works. The same is true for the way you suggested for output redirection at the end of the loop which I tried before posting: done < list >> "${dirname}/${logfile}"

Comment: I think you are talking about error messages of chown. They are written to the console using stderr. Stderr is stream 2, stdout is stream 1. You can tell the command to write stderr to the same place as stdout with `2>&1`. Make sure you first redirect stdout, so use `>> "${dirname}/${logfile}" 2>&1`.